# What options are there for displaying a presentation slideshow in C#?

Tags: c#, mono, cross-platform

#### The Scenario:

I need to create a lightweight presentation application that offers PowerPoint-like features such as:

- Simple text formatting (font, colour, size, style, etc)
- Picture embedding (possibly video as well)
- Simple animations (just slide, fade and appear actually)

The presentations themselves will be arrays (or Dictionaries) of strings from either a built-in database or a series of XML files (probably a combination of both).

I intend to develop and test the application, and create presentations on a Windows PC, and then display (and possibly edit) those presentations on a Linux-based PC.

#### The Options:

The options I know about are:

- **WinForms**

  - *Pros:*

    - No external code needed
  - *Cons:*

    - Limited screen redrawing ability
    - Limited/No animations available
- **[HTMLRenderer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/HtmlRenderer.aspx)**

  - *Pros:*

    - Proven reliable layout format (HTML 4.01 + CSS Level 2)
    - Code freely available for embedding
  - *Cons:*

    - Code hasn't been updated since 2009
    - Author's website gives 404, and his company website is incomplete.

My question is, quite simply, what other options are there? And which would be the best for my needs?

Answer (score 0):

I would be very tempted to do this using [Gtk-Sharp](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp) and to use [WebKitSharp](https://github.com/mono/webkit-sharp) for rendering full HTML documents ( no need to restrict yourself )

You could possibly allow your program to consume a zip file containing html docs and images, perhaps even javascript and css.

Both libraries sould allow you to quite easily write a c# application that will run on mono on linux or OSX or windows with .Net or Mono.

That said, Webkit sharp has not had much in the way of recent checkins..

Comment: I accept that embedding a rendering engine is an option, but I can't help but feel like it's overkill for my needs. Then again I always have a little voice in the back of my head telling my not to over-think things... I ignore it too often :P